# How do I know which button is touched from first activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, onclick, boolean

I have several buttons which take me to the same activity. And I would that particular counter is increased depending on which button is touched(from the previous activity). How do I know which button is touched without give error:
Example code with only two buttons. Activity A:

```
btnSi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            sumarSi=true;
            Intent aSiguiente = new Intent(Peliculas.this, ResultadosSiguientes.class);
            aSiguiente.putExtra("sumarSi", sumarSi);
            startActivity(aSiguiente);
            Peliculas.this.finish(); 
        }
    });

    btnNo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            sumarNo=true;
            Intent aSiguiente = new Intent(Peliculas.this, ResultadosSiguientes.class);
            aSiguiente.putExtra("sumarNo", sumarNo);
            startActivity(aSiguiente);
            Peliculas.this.finish(); 
        }
    });
```

Activity B (Oncreate):

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        Boolean r1 = extras.getBoolean("sumarSi");
        if(r1==true){
            rdo1++;
        }
        Boolean r2 = extras.getBoolean("sumarNo");
        if(r2==true){
            rdo2++;
        }
```

This gives me error because when I play btnSi button and go to the Activity B, extras.getBoolean("sumarNo"); fails because there is no data to receive. How I can fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  choose wrong way to mark which button was clicked

```
btnSi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent aSiguiente = new Intent(Peliculas.this, ResultadosSiguientes.class);
        aSiguiente.putExtra("button", 1);
        startActivity(aSiguiente);
        Peliculas.this.finish(); 
    }
});

btnNo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent aSiguiente = new Intent(Peliculas.this, ResultadosSiguientes.class);
        aSiguiente.putExtra("button", 2);
        startActivity(aSiguiente);
        Peliculas.this.finish(); 
    }
});
```

And in Activity A in onCreate() method change to:

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    int r = extras.getInt("button", -1);
    if(r==1){
        rdo1++;
    }
    if(r==2){
        rdo2++;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that works excellent! You saved me a lot of work. :)

Comment: Welcome I'm glad that I could help you :)